# TextRecognizer is not getting set up...TextRecognizer.isOperational() always returns false

Tags: android, ocr, vision

Code :   TextRecognizer detector = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();
detector.isOperational() always returns  FALSE

TextRecognizer is not getting set up...TextRecognizer.isOperational() always returns false

Answer (score 0):

TextRecognizer.isOperational() returns false
when there is no storage space or any other error.